# Removing not-configurable object from context

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm trying to remove function from `v8::Context` after done `Script::Run(...)` in clean context.

This [issue](https://codereview.chromium.org/854493004) removed method `ForceRemove` from `v8` API.

The question is how to remove function from context if its descriptor has `configurable: false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete non-deletable properties. As the codereview issue you linked to mentions, V8's API intentionally doesn't let you sidestep the rules of JavaScript.

I guess your goal is to reset a `v8::Context` to its pristine state? If that's the case, then a better approach is probably to create a new context instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes, my main goal is to 'clear' context without creation of new one.
I'm basically using it to execute some methods and have write-configure protected all builtins & c++ bindings before running any dynamic scripts in it.
Context creation is wasting 750us even with snapshot feature.

Comment: Well, if you're already limiting what the scripts can do, you can consider installing a "definer" interceptor on the global object and either prevent creation of non-configurable properties on it, or override/ignore the non-configurability bit.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need. Have u got any example or api reference for doing it?

Comment: Look for `GenericNamedPropertyDefinerCallback` and `IndexedPropertyDefinerCallback` in the V8 API. This test is an example: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/test/cctest/test-api-interceptors.cc?q=PropertyDefinerCallbackConfigurable&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=2008